# MVC Razor Charts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

Trying to add a chart inline to a view.

Folder structure:

```
"parent" view is in "views/account/AccountHome.cshtml"<br />
"chart" partial view is in "views/shared/ChartsPartial.cshtml"
```

If I add this code into the parent view

```
@Html.Partial("ChartsPartial")
```

the chart displays correctly as a (whole screen) image overlaying the view.
**So I know the code within ChartsPartial.cshtml works fine**

But I want to display the charts within the `AccountHome.cshtml` view.
So looking it up on Google (and following a number of questions on here), the suggestions were to add:

```
<img src="~/Views/Shared/ChartsPartial.cshtml" />
```

I use Visual Studio 2015 and this is the url it picked out using intellisense. But I've tried a number of combinations including the FULL url but to no avail.

All I get is a "image not found" icon instead of the chart.
Where am I going wrong?

For completeness, `ChartsPartial.cshtml` contains the following:

```
@model FiveADayMVC2.Models.fad_userFoods
@{
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
.AddTitle("Chart Title")
.AddSeries(
name: "Employee",
xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
.Write();
}
```

Comment: you should not use html tags to format your questions.  removing the `<p>` and `</br>`'s allowed the formatting to work

Comment: Thanks Roger. Accepted your formatting and removed unnecessary rants!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="~/Views/Shared/ChartsPartial.cshtml" />
```

This won't work ! You cannot directly access your razor view's in a browser ( and you should not!)

You should expose your view(s) via an action method in your controller. So create an action method in your `AccountController` which returns your partial view.

```
public ActionResult ShowChart()
{
    return PartialView("ChartsPartial");
}
```

And now in your main view (`AccountHome.cshtml`) you can do

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ShowChart","Account")" alt="Some alt text" />
```

Comment: I followed guidance from this page here:
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart (search on "Displaying Charts Inside a Web Page" for relevant part)
But your way seems more MVC so will try this now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Shyju, worked a treat.
Just goes to show, that Google can sometimes give you too many wrong answers. You have to sort the wheat from the chaff to find the correct one!